# Application unable to access table created in oracle database

Tags: oracle, cx-oracle

Fetching data through a python application from a table throws me this error:
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. I have verified the schema and table name.

```
cur = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM SYS.STUDENT_RECORDS')
```

However, the application fetches data from the system table.

```
cur = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TAB_STATS$ WHERE ROWNUM <= 10")
```

Here is the connection string:

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)                                                                     
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user='username', password='****',dsn=dsn_tns)
```

I am assuming it has got to do something with the user permission, but not quite getting it right. I don't have much experience with Oracle DB. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, why do you have user tables like student_records in sys schema? To answer your question, If you have DBA privileges, you could  give grants. It is better you ask your  DBA to give access to data dictionary for the schema user from which your python script logs into database.

Comment: `FROM SYS.STUDENT` never ever create tables under `SYS` or `SYSTEM` schema/user, unless you are going to destroy your database. Create a new, normal user (schema) and then put all your tables in this schema.

Comment: I followed the above instructions and tested the connection with this new user from SQL developer... but from the python script, I am unable to log in:   cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kaushik @krokodilko, your guidance helped me arrive at the following solution:

1. Created new user and granted privileges.
2. Changed connection string to use service name instead of SID.(don't know why SID didn't work though)

   ```
   dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, service_name=service_name)
   ```
3. ```
   cur = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user1.STUDENT_PROFILES WHERE ROWNUM <= 10")
   ```

Comment: On the service vs SID - the listener may not know of your SID - esp if the database is a 12c database in a multitenant architecture. The pluggable databases are ONLY addressable via their service name